# Gaussian adaptive thresholding

Tags: opencv, image-processing

In Gaussian adaptive thresholding, the threshold is calculated according to the local area in the image. What is the algorithm used in Gaussian adaptive thresholding?

Comment: what's wrong with referring to the manual?

Answer (score 2):

From the OpenCV manual:

[Adaptive Thresholding](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#ga72b913f352e4a1b1b397736707afcde3)

```
void cv::adaptiveThreshold  (   InputArray  src,
OutputArray     dst,
double  maxValue,
int     adaptiveMethod,
int     thresholdType,
int     blockSize,
double  C 
)
```

> where T(x,y) is a threshold calculated individually for each pixel
>   (see adaptiveMethod parameter)....
>
> **adaptiveMethod**    Adaptive thresholding algorithm to use, see
>   cv::AdaptiveThresholdTypes. The BORDER_REPLICATE | BORDER_ISOLATED is
>   used to process boundaries.
>
> the threshold value T(x,y) is a weighted sum (cross-correlation with a
>   Gaussian window) of the blockSize×blockSize neighborhood of (x,y)
>   minus C . The default sigma (standard deviation) is used for the
>   specified blockSize . See cv::getGaussianKernel

For even better information read the source code:

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/thresh.cpp